# List child pages, exclude the current page

Tags: child-pages, exclude

I'm trying to display the child pages of a parent page, this is working. But when I tried to exclude the current page in the list where the child pages displayed, it's not working.

How to fix this?

```
$current_post_id = $post->ID;
if(wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=2143&exclude='.$current_post_id.'")):
    if($title)
        echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;
        wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=2143&exclude='.$current_post_id.'");
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a syntax error to me. Try:

```
wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=2143&exclude=$current_post_id")
```

OR

```
wp_list_pages("title_li=&child_of=2143&exclude=".$current_post_id)
```

Also I will suggest to pass parameters as array instead of a string, for better debugging.

```
wp_list_pages( array(
    'child_of'    => 2143,
    'exclude'  => array( $current_post_id ),
);
```

Make sure `$current_post_id` is giving proper value.

Comment: still the current page displayed in the list

Comment: Try edited answer

Comment: still not working, the current page is not excluded in the child pages list

Comment: Is your `$current_post_id` value corect?

Answer (score 0):

How about using

```
$args = array(
    'post_parent' => 2143,
    'post_type'   => 'any', 
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'any' 
);
$children = get_children( $args );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children

Answer (score 0):

This always works for me:

```
$current_post_id = get_the_ID();
$child_pages = wp_list_pages( array(
    'title_li' => '',
    'sort_column' => 'post_date',
    'sort_order' => 'desc',
    'echo' => 0,    
    'exclude'  => ($current_post_id)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know its a little late answer but hoping it will be helpful for someone

```
    $parent_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $post->ID );

    wp_list_pages( array(
        'title_li' => '',
        'child_of'    => $parent_id,
        'depth'     => 1,
        'exclude'  => $post->ID
        )
    );
```